# How to get children with dynamic content centered AND the same width with flex?

Tags: css, flexbox

Okay, so, I know this is a long shot, but you never know, so I'll ask anyway.

I have a flex container that display 4 items which contents are dynamically generated (picked in a database). Which means I don't know what's inside of them. I just know it's some text with a certain maximum length. So I basically have something like this :

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Long item content</div>
  <div class="item">Short</div>
  <div class="item">Other content</div>
</div>
```

What I'd like would be for all the items to be the same size, which would be the size of the biggest of them (here the second one) to have something like this :

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 85%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.item {
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 1 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Long item content</div>
  <div class="item">Short</div>
  <div class="item">Other content</div>
</div>
```

but of course, without fiddling the container's width and position. I'd like the container to be 100% width, and the children to adapt their size to get this rendering.

Does anyone knows a way to do this?

I work with Angular, by the way.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You may want to use `display: grid`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [`display: grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid) instead?

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 4px;
  grid-row-gap: 4px;
}

.item {
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #aaaa00;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">Content</div>
  <div class="item">Long item content</div>
  <div class="item">Short</div>
  <div class="item">Other content</div>
  <div class="item">fifth element</div>
</div>
```

Added fifth element to show that grid layout is honored by further elements.